# If $g$ is surjective prove that $f$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra

$f: A \rightarrow B, \quad g: \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A), N \rightarrow f^{-1}(N)$

I want to show, that (a) $f$ is injective if $g$ is surjective and (b) $f$ is surjective if $g$ is injective.

My current thoughts are:

(a) If $g$ is surjective: $\{ y_1 \} \in \mathcal{P}(A) \Rightarrow \exists \{ x_1 \} \in \mathcal{P}(B): g(\{ x_1 \} ) = \{ y_1 \}$ and $\{ y_2 \} \in \mathcal{P}(A) \Rightarrow \exists \{ x_2 \} \in \mathcal{P}(B): g(\{ x_2 \} ) = \{ y_2 \}$

Let $x_1, x_2 \in A \quad x_1 = x_2$ then $\{ x_1 \} = \{ x_2 \}$

$\{ y_1 \} = g( \{ x_1 \} ) = g( \{ x_2 \} ) = \{ y_2 \}$, so $\{ y_1 \} = \{ y_2 \} \Leftrightarrow y_1 = y_2$. That means that f is injective.

For (b) I don’t know how to prove it, I tried the same way as above, but that didn’t result in anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

If $f$ is not injective then some $b$ will exists such that $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ has more than one element. If $x,y$ are distinct elements of $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ then no $N\in\wp(B)$ exists with $f^{-1}(N)=\{x\}$ so that $g$ is not surjective.

This because: $$x\in f^{-1}(N)\implies \{b\}=\{f(x)\}\subseteq N\implies y\in f^{-1}(\{b\})\subseteq f^{-1}(N)\implies f^{-1}(N)\neq\{x\}$$

Proved is now that $f$ is injective if $g$ is surjective.

b)

If $f$ is not surjective then some element $b\in B$ exists with: $$g(\{b\})=f^{-1}(\{b\})=\varnothing=f^{-1}(\varnothing)=g(\varnothing)$$ showing that $g$ is not injective.

Proved is now that $f$ is surjective if $g$ is injective.

---

edit for clarification:

Let it be that $f$ is not injective. Then $x,y\in A$ exists with $x\neq y$ and $f(x)=f(y)\in B$. Denoting this common value as $b$ we then have: $x,y\in f^{-1}(\{b\})$.

Now we claim that in this situation no set $N\subseteq B$ exists that satisfies $f^{-1}(N)=\{x\}$. A direct consequence of this is that $g$ is not surjective.

In order to prove that we assume that $N\subseteq B$ satisfies $f^{-1}(N)=\{x\}$ and based on that we will deduce a contradiction.

From $f^{-1}(N)=\{x\}$ it follows that $f(x)\in N$. Then also $f(y)=f(x)\in N$ or equivalently $y\in f^{-1}(N)=\{x\}$. That however contradicts that $x\neq y$.

Comment: I do not quite understand your prove for (a). I get what you did for (b) and understood it, so it would be very kind of you to explain your first prove to me.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a clarification.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. why is it, that $x,y \in f^{-1}(\{b \})$ and not $x,y \in  f^{-1}(b)$?

Comment: $f$ is a function $A\to B$. If $b\in B$ then $\{b\}\subseteq B$ and $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ denotes the preimage of $\{b\}$ under $f$. That means that by definition $f^{-1}(\{b\})=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in\{b\}\}=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=b\}$. Here $x,y$ are both elements of that set, because $f(x)=b$ and $f(y)=b$. The notation $f^{-1}(b)$ is actually an abuse of notation, oftenly used to abbreviate $f^{-1}(\{b\})$. Preimages are over sets, not over elements. You are allowed to use that notation, but be careful. You must know exactly what is going on.

Comment: oh ok thank you very much! now it is clear to me...

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer meets your needs then you can also accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b \in B$ and $A=f^{-1}(\{b\})=g(\{b\})$. If $A=\emptyset$ then, since $g(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $g$ is injective we get  $\{b\}=\emptyset$ which is false. Hence there is some point $a$ in $A=f^{-1}(\{b\})$ which gives $f(a)=b$. Hence $f$ is surjective.